# How to get a proper folder handle from a URI in Java?

Tags: java, file, uri

I noticed a little issue. What my application gets is a URI of a file e.g. `file:///C:/temp/somefolder/somedocument.txt` as a String.

What my application has to do is check the folder for more files and process them. To do that, I'd normally do something like

```
File file = new File(myURI);
File folder = file.getParentFile();
File[] peers = folder.getParentFile().listFiles();
```

Unfotunately, this doesn't seem to work at all when you use URI's. `.listFiles` always returns null, even if I open a `File()` handle to the URI of the folder.

Any ideas how to get around this problem?

P.S.: none of the methods of `File` or `java.net.URI` will return an absolute path which is not a URI ;)

Comment: The code is good, works fine. Please post the stacktrace if it's throwing any exception.

Comment: is myURI an object of type URI, or a string? It has to be the former.

Comment: I'm getting a String. And there's no exception whatsoever. The listFiles is simply null ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myURI` is actually a `String` representation of a `URI`. The constructor of `File` that you're calling is

```
public File(String pathname)
```

Note the `pathname` bit, it's not a URI-ish value.

Try

```
File file = new File(new URI(myURI));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually worked. Strangely enough, opening the file handle and working with it works perfectly fine with a URI-ish String as a parameter. It starts to behave strange only if you try the directory operations...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
File file = new File(myURI);
File[] peers = new File(file.getParent()).listFiles();
```

This worked for me. However if I use your code I get a NPE when I call getParentFile()