# URI for a directory path only?

Tags: java, io, uri, file-uri

Is it possible to define a URI representing a directory path only (i.e. with no actual file terminating the URI)? Example: `file:///path/to/files`.

I have the need to specify paths to directories to a Java program and would like to specify them as a URI rather than just a String directory path. The program receiving this information would treat the URI as a directory specifier and expect to read whatever files are contained within. It does not care what the file names are.

UPDATE:

If this is allowed, would I be able to "open" the URI in order to get the listing of files within, and then be able to open them for reading?

Comment: Apropos, if not a dupe (I'll leave that to others):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417056/how-to-get-a-proper-folder-handle-from-a-uri-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
here's an exemple 
lets say `myfolder` is a folder that contains 3 files (file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt).

```
URI uri = new URI("file:///c:/myfolder/");
File folder =new File(uri);
for(File file : folder.listFiles()){
System.out.println(file.getName()); 
}
```

the output will be :

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Comment: what about a URI for a file in "this directory"?  I try  "./my folder/" but it doesn't work. However "." does work..